# Why don't cfn-init logs get sent by rsyslog?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, amazon-cloudformation

I just signed up for [Papertrail](http://papertrailapp.com) to aggregate logs from some AWS instances I'm setting up with CloudFormation::Init.  I've followed the instructions and added `*.* @logs.papertrailapp.com` to the end of '/etc/rsyslog.conf'.  Some logs are showing up on Papertrail, but notably the contents of '/var/log/cfn-init.log' never get there, and those are the ones I'm interested in right now.

Have I set up rsyslog incorrectly?  Or do the CloudFormation::Init scripts just not use syslog to write log information?

Answer (score 0):

`cfn-init`, the Python script which handles CloudFormation::Init, writes logs directly to disk.  There doesn't appear to be any way to configure it to use syslog.